# ¿Por que no puedo instalar con pip el Sunpy?

Tags: python

Hola estoy tratando de instalar Sunpy por medio del comando:
pip install sunpy

Sin embargo, no se por que me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hx3bazic\overlay\Lib\site- 
packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:207: _Warning: Package 'multidict._multilib' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
       !!

          
********************************************************************************
              ############################
              # Package would be ignored #
              ############################
              Python recognizes 'multidict._multilib' as an importable package[^1],
              but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.

              This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to 
distribute this
              package, please make sure that 'multidict._multilib' is explicitly added
              to the `packages` configuration field.

              Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
              (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
              instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).

              You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html

              If you don't want 'multidict._multilib' to be distributed and are
              already explicitly excluding 'multidict._multilib' via
              `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or 
`find_packages(...)/find`,
              you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, orm `include-package-
```

data=False`in combination with a more fine grained`package-
data` configuration.

```
You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools 
documentation page:

              - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html


              [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                    even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                    On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                    directory, all directories are treated like packages.
          
********************************************************************************

      !!
        check. Warn(importable)
      copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
      running build_ext
      building 'multidict._multidict' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install 
pyproject.toml-based projects
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: El error te lo esta dando multidict. Una de las dependencias de sunpy es parfive, que a su vez depende de aiohttp y este a su vez de multidict. Multidict aun no tiene disponibles los wheels precompilados para Python 3.12 ([issue en Github](https://github.com/aio-libs/multidict/issues/887)), por lo que intenta compilarlo desde las fuentes y es aqui donde falla ya que tu sistema no tiene los requerimientos necesarios, prueba a instalar Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 tal como dice el propio error.

Comment: Pudes usar [Build Tools for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) para instalar C++ Build Tools